# Issues with numpy installation: ModuleNotFoundError & Invalid metadata entry

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

I've been trying to run a script from a project I cloned, but I consistently receive the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘numpy'

To address this, I attempted to install `numpy` using `pip`, but I received a warning related to an invalid metadata entry:

```
WARNING: Skipping /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy-1.26.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.25.0)
WARNING: Skipping /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy-1.26.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry ‘name'
```

It seems I have a conflict between two numpy versions, and even after attempting to uninstall and reinstall numpy, the problem persists. I also ensured I'm working in the correct Python environment.

Any suggestions on how to properly resolve this and get numpy to work as expected? Any help would be much appreciated!